¿Cómo puedo redirigir las URL de tiendas de mis clientes, que actualmente se ven bajo mi dominio, para que se vean bajo el dominio de cada cliente?
Quiero redirigir las tiendas de mis clientes, que actualmente se encuentran bajo mi dominio (por ejemplo, midominio.com/tienda/cliente1), de modo que se vean bajo el dominio de cada cliente (por ejemplo, clientedominio.com/tienda). ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de configurar esta redirección y qué pasos debo seguir para asegurarme de que todo funcione correctamente?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
